# On Basak's "Bounds On Factors Of Odd Perfect Numbers"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) given in Eulerian form, i.e. $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  In what follows, we denote the abundancy index of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$, where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of the divisors of $x$.

In *Case 1* under *Remark 3.1* on page 4 of Basak's [Bounds On Factors Of Odd Perfect Numbers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.4733.pdf), it is proven that

$$\frac{16}{7\zeta(3)} < \frac{16q^3}{7\zeta(3)(q^3 - 1)} < \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{q}\bigg)\prod_{p \mid n, \hspace{0.05in} p \neq q}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2}\bigg).$$

But we also have
$$\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{q}\bigg)\prod_{p \mid n, \hspace{0.05in} p \neq q}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2}\bigg) < I(q)I(n^2) \leq \frac{6I(n^2)}{5},$$
since $q$ is prime with $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $q \geq 5$.

(Note that this last inequality is unconditional on the truth of the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture that $k=1$.)

This implies that
$$\frac{16}{7\zeta(3)} < \frac{6I(n^2)}{5}$$
from which it follows that
$$I(n^2) > \frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{16}{7\zeta(3)} = \frac{40}{21\zeta(3)} \approx 1.58458547158229994034881195966.$$

But then this resulting numerical lower bound for $I(n^2)$ is trivial, as it is known that
$$I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q - 1} \leq \frac{5}{4} < \frac{8}{5} \leq \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} < I(n^2),$$
so that we already know, unconditionally, that $I(n^2) > 1.6$.

Here is my question:

> Would it be possible to tweak Basak's argument in order to come up with an improved lower bound for
>   $$\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{q}\bigg)\prod_{p \mid n, \hspace{0.05in} p \neq q}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2}\bigg)?$$

**Update (May 1, 2020 - 13:45 PM Manila time)**

> I re-read Basak's argument in *Case 1* under *Remark 3.1* on page 4 of the hyperlinked paper in arXiv, it appears that Basak does make use of the assumption that $k=1$.

Comment: Note that, when $k=1$, then we have the lower bound
$$I(n^2) \geq \frac{5}{3} = 1.\overline{666}$$
where equality holds if and only if $q=5$.

Comment: After taking to Basak:

"... the same year a paper was published by Anirudh Prabhu in the United States which used different methods to obtain bounds for the reciprocal sums of prime factors. The constraints on OPNs produced are different, but seem slightly stronger." 

The link to Prabhu's paper is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1114).

Comment: We get$$\frac{16q^3}{7\zeta(3)(q^3 - 1)} <  I(q)I(n^2)$$from which we have$$I(n^2)\gt\frac{16}{7\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q^4}{(q^3-1)(q+1)}\ge \frac{16}{7\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{5^4}{(5^3-1)(5+1)}\approx 1.59736$$which is better than $1.584585$, but still smaller than $1.6$.

Comment: I think though, @mathlove, that $q^4/((q^3 - 1)(q - 1)) = 1/((1 - (1/q)^3)(1 - (1/q)))$, so that we obtain $q \geq 5$ implies that
$$q^3 \geq 125 \implies (1/q)^3 \leq 1/125 \implies 1 - (1/q)^3 \geq 124/125 \implies 1/(1 - (1/q)^3) \leq 125/124.$$
Similarly, we get
$$q \geq 5 \implies 1/q \leq 1/5 \implies 1 - (1/q) \geq 4/5 \implies 1/(1 - (1/q)) \leq 5/4.$$

Comment: My computations in the previous comment imply that
$$\frac{q^4}{(q^3 - 1)(q + 1)}$$
is bounded from **above** by $625/496$, and **not from below**, @mathlove.

Comment: We have $q^4/((q^3-1)(q\color{red}{+}1))$. But you wrote $q^4/((q^3-1)(q\color{red}{-}1))$. Is this just a typo? Note that $q^4/((q^3-1)(q\color{red}{+}1))$ is increasing, but $q^4/((q^3-1)(q\color{red}{-}1))$ is decreasing.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Indeed,
$$\frac{q^4}{(q^3 - 1)(q + 1)} \geq \frac{625}{744}$$
for $q \geq 5$.  The WolframAlpha computational verification is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+q%5E4%2F%28%28q%5E3+-+1%29%28q+%2B+1%29%29+subject+to+q+%3E%3D+5).

Comment: Please write out your comments as an actual answer, @mathlove, so that I may be able to upvote it, as it definitely improves on the lower bound for $I(n^2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get $$\frac{16q^3}{7\zeta(3)(q^3 - 1)} <  I(q)I(n^2)$$ from which we have

$$I(n^2)\gt\frac{16}{7\zeta(3)}f(q)$$
where
$$f(q)=\frac{q^4}{(q^3-1)(q+1)}$$

Now, we have, for $q\ge 5$, 
$$f'(q)=\frac{ q^3 (q(q^2-3)-4)}{(q + 1)^2 (q^3 - 1)^2}\gt 0$$
from which we have

$$I(n^2)\gt\frac{16}{7\zeta(3)}f(q)\ge \frac{16}{7\zeta(3)}f(5)=\frac{1250}{651\zeta(3)}\approx 1.597364$$
which is better than $1.584585$, but still smaller than $1.6$.

Comment: Which CAS did you perform your computations in?

Comment: @AdamL, I think it is best to perform the computations for this one in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris  if you say so boss :-P

Comment: Gladly accepting your answer now, @mathlove!  =)